# Is there any way to determine whether a new Ubuntu release is available from the command line?

Tags: ubuntu, upgrade

Normally in Ubuntu if a new release is available the GUI will tell you.  However, if you're running Ubuntu on the server, there is no GUI.

You *can* run `lsb_release -a`, which will at least tell you what your current release is, but that doesn't tell you whether there is a new release you can upgrade to.  I'm trying to write a dead-simple "determine whether it's upgrade time" script, and it would be really handy to be able to do so via a command ... does anyone know one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the command `do-release-upgrade`. If there is no new version available, it simply returns accordingly:

```
$ do-release-upgrade 
Checking for a new ubuntu release
No new release found
```

If there is a new release available, however, it goes on downloading the differences, asking for sudo password (if run by non-privileged user for upgrades).

For LTS versions of Ubuntu, I believe it only shows that there is an upgrade available if there is a new LTS version available. Do some more research of the tool to see its exact quirks.

Comment: I knew about do-release-upgrade, but didn't think it could be used "diagnostically" until I read your "run without sudo" idea; thanks!

Comment: Adding -s will also just show what it would have done, without actually doing anything. You can do this for instance to time an upgrade.